# how to get the output of each() function in perl when using key value pairs?

Tags: perl, hash, each, key-pair

```
%group = ( 'forest', 'tree', 'crowd', 'person', 'fleet', 'ship' );

while ( ( $key, $value ) = each(%group) ) {
    print "A $value is part of a $key.\n";
}
```

This is the code and the output is this

```
A person is part of a crowd.
A tree is part of a forest.
A ship is part of a fleet.
```

why don't I get the output according to the order I have given in the array?

Comment: That is not an array you specified. It us a hasmap and this has no order-

Comment: As Jens has pointed out, you are using a hash which has no notion of order. Check out [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638690/iterating-hash-based-on-the-insertion-order) for possible solution which uses `Tie::IxHash` module.

Comment: i had this question in an exam and i had to write the output..how do i know that the output is given like that without it being A tree is part of a forest,A person is part of a crowd.,A ship is part of a fleet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an array, you have a hash. Hashes are unordered. If you want to impose order on your data, then use an array.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @groups = (
  [ 'forest','tree' ],
  [ 'crowd','person' ],
  [ 'fleet','ship' ],
);

foreach my $group (@groups) {
   say "A $group->[1] is part of a $group->[0].";
}
```